# Downloading SSRS report from report server using C# code

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have been working on a requirement to deploy and download SSRS reports programmatically from C# code.

I used the service exposed by SSRS (ReportingServices2010). I am able to deploy my reports from application server to report server successfully. I referred to "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43133/Deploying-Reports-in-Reporting-Services-Programmat" for this.

Meaning, the deployment portion is done and I am able to deploy the report using C# code. But now, I want a functionality to download reports from report server and place it to Application server somewhere. I want to achieve this in similar way, like I did for deploying (using C# code).

But I am unable to find any method exposed by service which can return content of the report deployed on report server.

As a work around I found a way to directly query on Report Server Database or Power shell script as well. But I would prefer a solution using C# code only.

Please suggest if we can download SSRS report from report server programmatically using C# code.

Thanks,
Ketan

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code for command Out-RsCatalogItem in [ReportingServicesTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools) GitHub project to determine how to download using the SOAP Proxy. In order to create a Web Service Proxy in .NET, look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/creating-the-web-service-proxy). If you are still not sure how to proceed, then leave a comment and I will try to hack up a quick sample.